# Making an iPad App that works without internet

Tags: ipad, cordova, titanium, development-environment

I am intending to make an app that works without the Internet. My App is just a presentation for my company and it would just be a page with links, link to PDFs and couple of videos.

It also has a questionnaire which would require results to be shown in a graph.

Is it possible?

Can I do it all without accessing internet? Could I use third party apps like phone gap, Corona, Rho Field, Widget Field, Appcelerator or others to speed up the process?

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can use phonegap. I do not have experience of other technologies you have mentioned. Phonegap has nice APIs for app development and day by day they are improving too. Seems phonegap will fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Using Titanium just install the plaftorm http://www.appcelerator.com/

Download the KitchenSink project https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink

and copy all the stuff you need to your own project.

Using webviews you could show local PDF's